# Проблема при изменении исходного списка при рекурсивной сортировке

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Решил написать некое подобие быстрой сортировки. Основная идея: ведущий элемент - крайний правый, изначальная граница - 0. Происходит проверка для каждого элемента от 0 до предпоследнего: если этот элемент меньше, чем ведущий, то этот элемент меняется местами с элементом на позиции **border**, затем **border** увеличивается на 1.

После этого этот алгоритм применяется к левой и правой частям полученного массива.

Столкнулся с проблемой: исходный список не изменяется при глубине сортировки, большей, чем 2, то есть после того, как функция сработает 1 раз и вызовет сама себя, исходный массив перестаёт изменяться.

**Сам код:**

```
ar = [5, 1, 6, 3, 4, 2]
def quick(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return 

    pivot = -1
    border = 0

    for t in range(0,len(a)-1):
        if a[t] < a[pivot]:  # если элемент меньше, чем ведущий
            print(a[t], a[pivot])
            a[border], a[t] = a[t], a[border]
            border += 1

    # меняем ведущий элемент и элемент на границе местами
    a[border], a[pivot] = a[pivot], a[border] 

    quick(a[0:border])  # сортируем левую часть

    if border + 1 < len(a):
        quick(a[border+1:len(a)])  # сортируем правую часть

quick(ar)
print(ar)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что slice создает копию списка:

```
def foo(l):
  l[0] = 1

l = [1,2,3]
foo(l[1:])
print(l) # -> [1,2,3]
```

Как правильно ответили уже, возвращайте измененный (отсортированный) список:

```
def foo(l):
  l[0] = 1
  return l

l = [1,2,3]
l[1:] = foo(l[1:])
print(l) # -> [1,1,3]
```

Т.е. в Вашем случае:

```
def quick(a):
  ...
  a[0:border] = quick(a[0:border])
  if ...
     a[border+1:len(a)] = quick(a[border+1:len(a)])
  return a
```

Answer (score 1):

При отладке показало, что функция вызывается и сортирует. Просто из-за того что она ничего не возвращает, результат сортировки удаляется. Попробуй переделать функцию, чтобы она возвращала значение списка от border+1:len(ar) [уже отсортированого] и присваивало эти значения начальному списку